# DW weapon slotting - weapon speed

Tags: diablo-iii

This is probably a stupid question, but need to know if i had two weapons:
A - DPS 100, attack speed 2 (these are all hyperthetical figures ofcourse)
B - DPS 200. attack speed 1

Does it matter which i put in the left or right hand? I hear to put the higher speed weapon on the primary slot.

Is this true and is there any other things to note when slotting weapons?

Comment: I think this question has what you're looking for: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68383/attack-speed-and-its-interaction-with-various-skills