# What affects projectile speed?

Tags: diablo-iii

What factors have any effect on the traveling speed of a cast projectile?
Is it the same all over, regardless of attack speed or other boni?

Are there any skills or equipments which do affect projectile speed?

([This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68383/attack-speed-and-its-interaction-with-various-skills) covers the mechanics of attack speed but I can't figure out whether it can increase projectile speed (Wizard, Demon Hunter etc.), if it is ever possible.)

Comment: AFAIK only [Slow Time](http://www.diablowiki.net/Slow_Time) has any effect on projectile speed, though I only play Wizard personally.

Comment: @Thebluefish I mean your own projectile speed. Offensively, not defensively.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of modifies player projectile speed. I remember some people did fairly extensive frame-by-frame testing around the time the game came out, but nothing that I can find appears to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware of, no items in the game can increase your projectile travelling speed.

However :

- Some skills like [Arcane Orb](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/arcane-orb) provide a rune (Obliteration) that increase the projectile speed.
- Elites with the affixe "Missile Dampening" can slow them.

From the game guide :

> Missile dampening monsters project an aura that slows your incoming
>   projectiles, making ranged attacks less effective.

Comment: Not true, runes can increase projectile speed: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/arcane-orb using Obliteration for example.

Comment: @Blindy Thanks, I did not noticed that while browsing skills on my wizard. Do you happen to know if there are any special legendary with a property to increase  the projectile speed. I can't think of any at the moment but I might be wrong

Comment: I haven't seen any legendaries so far that boost projectile speed.