# Is fire rate included in the damage for Demon Hunter's Rapid Fire

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does weapon speed affect animation speed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50213/does-weapon-speed-affect-animation-speed)

All Demon Hunter's [Rapid Fire](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/rapid-fire) skill says is

> Rapidly fire for 228% weapon damage as Physical

Is this affected at all by the weapon's default fire rate?

If the answer is no, it seems logical that a DH should favor damage over attack speed when upping his DPS.

Comment: Try for yourself with a frenzy shrine. The speed up is pretty noticeable from the sound alone.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicated, nor does it have anything to do with the linked question. He is asking about the effect of a particular skill, which is vague in its wording.

Comment: I agree, this definitely isn't a duplicate of the question listed. To answer the question, yes your Rapid Fire skill is affected by your attack rate. This is noticeable when you switch between a slow or a fast weapon, or like Raven said if you use a Frenzy shrine. I think it speeds up your fire rate by 228%, however I am not positive of that.

Comment: Thanks Rachel - that helps a lot.  If Raven Dreamer un-duplicates it I'd gladly vote up/accept as the answer.

Comment: I was already writing an answer and it wouldn't post.. then I found out I was closed :/ I was explaining how almost everything is percentage based and it made sense for the developers to re-use effects like "+ Attack Speed"