# Does Attack Speed % affect Acid Cloud Spamming?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does weapon speed affect animation speed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50213/does-weapon-speed-affect-animation-speed)

Working on my gear for my Witch Doctor and unsure about using Attack Speed increase weapons for AOE acid cloud spam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it increases your casting animation so you can spam it faster, if you are looking at raising your weapon damage (for skills) attack speed does not increase the damage it will do.